# EC2 Volume "In use" but no attachment information

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have an EBS volume that is showing as "In Use" in the console, but the attachment field is blank.

ec2-describe-volumes shows the same information, while ec2-describe-volume-status throws an exception.

How can I find out what, if anything, is using this volume?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen both EC2 instances and EBS volumes get wedged like this from time to time. Typically the only resolution path is to contact AWS support.

If you have a support plan (you should), it's very easy and fast to submit a ticket. If not, you just post in the support forums and pray that one of their engineers sees your post and takes pity on you.